# Pass connection string to execute process task SSIS

Tags: ssis

I need to pass an argument to process task and it's a connection string and value should be picked from one of the connections in Connection Managers. How do I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i would store the connection strings in a table and use Parent Child configurations with property expressions

if you a variable in a package then you will need to modify it manually, not so good